# How to render multiple views with template engine

Tags: express, ejs, render

I'm developing a community website using express, that changes UI according to user info.
So the server should react to both url path and query.
Maybe I can make all ejs files that matches each url path and query combination, But that would create a lot of duplicate..

I knew this wouldn't work, but I want to do like this

```
root
  index.js
  views
    layout.ejs
    community.ejs
    topic
      man.ejs
      woman.ejs
```

index.js

```
...
APP.get('communiity', (req, res) => {
    res.render('community')
    if(req.query['sex']=='man'){
        res.render('topic/man')
    } 
    else{
        res.render('topic/woman')
    }
})
```

Comment: maybe include is the solution-I'm just trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do this by using include.

```
root
  index.js
  views
    layout.ejs
    community.ejs
    topic
      man.ejs
      woman.ejs
```

index.js

```
...

APP.get('communiity', (req, res) => {
    res.render('community',{sex:res.query['sex'])}

...
```

community.ejs

```
...

<%if(sex=='man')%>
    <%-include('topic/man.ejs')%>
<%}%>
<%else{%>
    <%-include('topic/woman.ejs')%>
<%}%>

...
```